# How to avoid storing duplicates in a Set if the objects type comes from a compiled .class file?

Tags: java, duplicates, set, .class-file

I am trying to store objects in a **Set** to **avoid duplicates**.

As this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776813/how-to-store-unique-objects-to-avoid-the-duplicates-in-java-set) explains I need to **@Override** two methods: **hashCode()** and **equals(Object obj)**.

The objects type that I am trying to store in the above **Set** comes from a compiled ***.class*** file and it doesn't have **hashCode()** and **equals(Object obj)** methods and either it's parents on inheritance chain (except **Object**).

Is there a way to store them in a **Set** to **avoid duplicates**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot modify the objects, then you can wrap them.

```
class EmployeeHolder {
  private final Employee employee;
  public int hashCode() { ... }
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (!(o instanceof EmployeeHolder)) return false;
    ...
  }
}
Set<EmployeeHolder> set = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: I understand that I will have a Set<EmployeeHolder> to use its hashCode() and equals(Object o) methods, but in the end I will need a Set<Employee>. After Set<EmployeeHolder> is populated I will have to cross it to extract each Employee. 
If this is right, is any more efficient way to do this?

Comment: No, there isn't.  But _why_ do you need a `Set<Employee>`?  What can you do with it that you can't do with a `Set<EmployeeHolder>`?

Comment: `Set<Employee> realSet = oldSet.map(EmployeeHolder::getEmployee).collect(Collectors.toSet());`  This will require a getter in the Employee holder class.  As an alternative you can duplicate the methods in your `Employeeholder` class to match those of the `Employee` class.  When those methods are called, just pass the call to the `Employee` instance and return the result.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I did some refactor and I'm still using some legacy code methods. Those methods use a specific format of data `Employee` in this case.
@WJS For the first part of your answer I wasn't asking for a mapping solution. For the second part of your answer as I explained above, I cannot get rid of `Employee` because it is still used in legacy code I'm dealing with.

Comment: If you can live with O(log n) lookup rather than O(1) lookup, you can use a `TreeSet` with a custom comparator. Alternatively, you can create a subclass of `AbstractSet<Employee>` that delegates to a `HashSet<EmployeeHolder>` for `add`, `size()`, and `contains` checks and implements methods like `iterator()` using the pattern shown by @WJS You only need the `size()` method and the `iterator()` to get a valid `Set` implementation, `add` to make it mutable, but `contains` is already a nice-to-have optimizations. It’s as simple as that.